# Need Tkinter login GUI help, invalid command name "4396910272update" error

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter, customtkinter

I currently have an program that uses the notebook widget in tkinter and runs with:

```
root = tk.Tk()
main = Main_view(root)
main.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to add a login in screen to the program. Having it as a login that changes straight into the app or a login that creates a new window and destroys itself is both okay.

I tried doing it like

```
ctk = customtkinter.CTk()
login_win = Login(ctk)
login_win.mainloop()
```

where it creates a login screen when the correct credentials is applied, the login button activates:

```
def logged_in(self):
    if self.username.get() == "123" and self.password.get() == "qwe":
        login_win.login_win.destroy()  # destroy current window and creating new one
        root = tk.Tk()
        main = Main_view(root)
        main.grid(row=0, column=0)
        root.mainloop()
```

but it sometimes crashes and always gives an error called.

`invalid command name "4396910272update"`